# ElasticSearch query a specific term, not other terms

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When I query for a term (standard-analyzer), I get a list of results sorted on score. Which is good. But when calling:

```
QueryBuilders.termQuery(fieldname, word);
```

I get a mixture of:

```
word
some word
WORD
word and such
```

In no particular ordering, since all score the same, because they all contain `word`. Since the number of results vary between 0 and towards 1M, I need to most exact matches first (or the others filtered).
I tried adding [based on ES regex filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), but looks like they are not being processed:

```
FilterBuilders.regexQuery(fieldname, "~"+word).flag(RegexpFlag.ALL);
FilterBuilders.regexQuery(fieldname, "^((?!" + word+").)*$".flag(RegexpFlag.ALL);// and this
FilterBuilders.regexQuery(fieldname, "^\\(\\(\\?!" + word+"\\)\\.\\)*$".flag(RegexpFlag.ALL);// or
```

I've also tried the `QueryBuilders.boostingQuery` which I also seem to fail in - besides I came across some comments that the negative querying does not work.

So basically, I'm looking for a query that queries for a particular term, while filtering/negative boosting the results that contains other words.
If possible I'd what to stay away from scripting for now (bad experiences).

So query: Must/should not contain a word different from word

Comment: For downvote, please mention why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the most easy set of queries is:

```
final int fetchAmount = 100; // number of items to return
final FilterBuilder filterBuilder = FilterBuilders.termFilter(fieldname, word);
final QueryBuilder combinedQuery = QueryBuilders.termQuery(fieldname, word);
final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(combinedQuery, filterBuilder);
final SearchResponse builder = CLIENT.prepareSearch(index_name).setQuery(queryBuilder).setExplain(true)
        .setTypes(type_name).setSize(fetchAmount).setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH).execute().actionGet();
```

Using the `FilterBuilder` to, cheaply, discard the values that don't contain `word`. Use the same query (`TermQuery`) for the `QueryBuilder` will result in a scoring mechanism. Take the score `SearchHit.score()` from the first, then continue until one is found for which the `score < firstScore`.
The problem, as described in question, occurs when instead of using `TermQuery` for `QueryBuilder` `QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()` is used. The same set of results will be returned in the latter case, but no scoring (hence no sorting) mechanism is applied.

Keep the `setSize` relatively low, for speed purposes, when the last item is still of interest, call the above query again, but then add `setFrom(fetchAmount )` so that the second query will start where the first one stopped, like:

```
final int xthQueryCalledTime = 1; // if using a loop
final SearchResponse builder = CLIENT.prepareSearch(index_name).setQuery(queryBuilder).setExplain(true)
        .setTypes(type_name).setSize(fetchAmount).setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setFrom(fetchAmount * xthQueryCalledTime).execute().actionGet();
```

Do until done.

Ps. Don't using scroll! This will mix-up the score ordering. From JavaDoc on SearchType.SCAN:

> Performs scanning of the results which executes the search without any sorting. It will automatically start scrolling the result set